# How do I remove effects from HTML button?

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

Trying to create a form designer in JavaScript which allows the user to move, re-size and rotate elements.

To do this I need to remove all effects from the button such as hover, click (or active).

Similar to what Visual Studio form designer does, no effects on the controls when placing and moving them on the form.

Not sure on the best approach, though I don't want to replace them with images because of re-sizing and naming the button.

I appreciate any help.

**EDIT:**

Seems I have fixed this by using the following code:

```
element.onfocus = function(e) {
    this.blur();
    return false;
};
```

Comment: Are you only talking about styles or also about event-driven behavior?

Comment: It would be the style of the button, the events need to remain so I can use the click events etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
input, input:focus, input:hover, input:active {
    outline: none;
    box-shadow:none;
}
```

If you want to remove remove all effect from `button`, replace input with `button`:

```
button, button:focus, button:hover, button:active {
    outline: none;
    box-shadow:none;
}
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/63B8s/1/)**

Comment: This is similar to what I want but I still want to keep the appearance of the button. Any possible way to do that? thanks

Comment: Updated answer for you :)

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, yes I want the button to appear just as normal but removing the button effects on hover and click. For example this is the mouse down effect: http://i.imgur.com/m1cDc8g.png I am trying to remove this effect so it just looks like: http://i.imgur.com/ZjG4ySl.png but without the outline. Just a normal button without the "effects".

Comment: seems I have fixed the issue now, thanks for help anyway.

Comment: you could use `outline:0` but it changes the layout

Answer (score 0):

This should just about remove all styles of a `<button/>` element:

```
button, button:active, button:focus{
  border:none;
  background:#fff;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  outline:none;
}
```

Demo here:
http://codepen.io/EightArmsHQ/pen/qJHas